# Hold gizmo axis transformation shortcut

Tags: 3d-view, customization, shortcut, 3d-cursor

In 3D Viewport constructions is usual to rotate the visualization often, so as it's gizmo stay at top-left side of application I observed me moving the mouse a lot.

There would be a keyboard shortcut to simulate holding an axis?
Or is possible to create this shortcut?

Comment: What do you mean by "holding an axis" ? You can easily rotate the view by pressing the middle mouse button and moving the mouse. You can use the numpad keys to set the view to front (1), right (3), top (7), back (ctrl+1), left (ctrl+3), bottom (ctrl+7).

Comment: Right! The middle mouse button function was what I have been looking for! Thanks @thibsert
Would you like to formulate an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily rotate the view by pressing the middle mouse button and moving the mouse. To pan the view, do the same but also maintain <kbd>Shift</kbd>. To zoom in/out, do the same but also maintain <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> (or simply use the mouse wheel).

You can use the numpad keys to set the view to :

- front <kbd>1</kbd>, back <kbd>Ctrl+1</kbd>
- right <kbd>3</kbd>, left <kbd>Ctrl+3</kbd>
- top <kbd>7</kbd>, bottom <kbd>Ctrl+7</kbd>
- camera <kbd>0</kbd>